# ruby on rails calculation total of table value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can the total of a variable I define be calculated?

I have:

product_sale.rb

```
def totalprice
  price*quantity
end
```

view

```
%h1 Listing Product Sales
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Product name
      %th Price
      %th Quantity
      %th Total price
  %tbody
    - @product_sales.each do |product_sale|
      %tr
        %td= product_sale.product_name
        %td= product_sale.price
        %td= product_sale.quantity
        %td= product_sale.totalprice
%br
%h1
  Total sum to be paid:
  = Product_sale.sum(:totalprice)
```

the `= Product_sale.sum(:totalprice)` does not work. How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@product_sales.map(&:totalprice).sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@product_sales.sum('price * quantity') # single query, efficient
```

P.S. Correct name for the class is snakecased `ProductSale`

Comment: `Product_sale` should be `ProductSale` :)

Comment: @Pavan indeed, but I just copied the OP's code - who knows, might be he called the class `Product_sale` :)..

Answer (score 0):

```
@product_sales.sum(&:totalprice)
```

I think this should work where you only sum the total price of the selected product sales

Comment: `sum` operates on database. there is no column `totalprice` in db, so this will throw wrong SQL error.

Answer (score 0):

`@product_sales.sum('price * quantity')`

Comment: what's the point of **this** answer, when [this same approach has already been proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35455170/1772830)?

Comment: the object @product_sales (maybe already filtered) and not to all table data

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for me was the one of Max:

controller index view: `@some_total = @product_sales.map(&:totalprice).sum`

view: `= @some_total`